# Save the entered value in textInput and display it after restarting my application

Tags: python, kivy

I need help because I do not know how the text entered by me in textInput would remain the same after restarting the application and I do not mean that in the .kv file I am writing text: only text
typed manually by me
if someone gave an example of gratitude

Answer (score 1):

Knowledges to have:

- Create a kivy App
- [load and save a string from/in a file](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.storage.html)
- [Get/Set value from/in a TextInput](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.textinput.html)
- Bind an event on the closing of the app to save you data `Window.bind(on_request_close=self.on_request_close)`

If you are able to do theses 4 steps, you will be able to do what you want.
When you are lost, cut your problematic into sub-problematic. :)